# SQL ROUND decimal and display as varchar

Tags: sql-server, decimal, rounding

I have some decimal fields in my table. I am trying to ROUND them and display in the desired format. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #SummaryData(
[ColA] [decimal](18, 1) NULL,
[ColB] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[ColC] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
[ColD] [decimal](18, 4) NULL,
[ColE] [decimal](18, 4) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #SummaryData ([ColA],[ColB],[ColC],[ColD],[ColE])
VALUES (36754.0 ,9090.07,   2.4507  ,33536.0000 ,0.0073)

INSERT INTO #SummaryData ([ColA],[ColB],[ColC],[ColD],[ColE])
VALUES (54978.0 , 12535.32  , 9.9419,47041.0000,    0.0088)

INSERT INTO #SummaryData ([ColA],[ColB],[ColC],[ColD],[ColE])
VALUES (53501.0,    13346.62,   2.8152, 32371.0000, 0.0042)

SELECT [ColA],[ColB],[ColC],[ColD],[ColE] 
FROM #SummaryData


-- We need data to be displayed like this for the purpose of reporting
ColA      ColB         ColC   ColD    ColE
----------------------------------------
36,754     9090        2.46   33.5%   0.7%
```

I tried to use ROUND and convert to varchar but did not work. Not sure how to get rid of zeros after decimal and apply "," (commas). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(cola as money), 1), 1, LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(cola as money), 1)) - 3) AS ColA, 
    CONVERT(INT, ColB) AS ColB,
    CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2), ColC) AS ColC, 
    FORMAT(ColD / 100000., 'p1') AS ColD, 
    FORMAT(ColE, 'p1') AS ColE
FROM #SummaryData
```

Here's the output:

```
36,754   9090    2.45   33.5 %   0.7 %
54,978   12535   9.94   47.0 %   0.9 %
53,501   13346   2.82   32.4 %   0.4 %
```

Comment: perfect! Thank you

Comment: Great @Silverfish - can you mark this as the correct answer? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FORMAT(ColA, '#,###')  AS ColA, 
    CAST(ColB AS INT) AS ColB,
    CAST(ColC AS INT) AS ColC, 
    FORMAT(ColD / 100000., 'p1') AS ColD, 
    FORMAT(ColE, 'p1') AS ColE
FROM #SummaryData


The output is:

ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD    ColE
36,754  9090    2       33.5 %  0.7 %
54,978  12535   9       47.0 %  0.9 %
53,501  13346   2       32.4 %  0.4 %
```

Comment: FORMAT(ColA, '#,###') is a good solution for ColA. I didn't know that worked. So does FORMAT(ColA, '#,#'), apparently.